# Copied file to have the same owner as its directory

Tags: filesystems, ownership

Let's say that

- my user account is `homer`
- there is a background service `marge` running an account `bart`.
- `marge` is using a directory `lisa` for its data.
- I have set the owner of `lisa` to `bart`.

If I create a file and try to copy it to `lisa`, it fails due to permission. I can copy it by `sudo cp`, but then, the file's owner becomes `root`, which `bart` cannot read. I want the owner of all files in `lisa` to be `bart`. I can manually change the owner of the file to `bart` after copying it into `lisa`, but can't it be automatically done? That is, I want the owner of all files in `lisa`, no matter who copied/created them into `lisa`, to be `bart` by default.

Comment: if you can use sudo then what about *sudo -u bart cp whatever /pathtolisa* ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you add a setgid bit on the directory `bart` like `chmod 2775 bart; chgrp maggie bart`, then all files inside the directory will have group ownership changed to `maggie`, and add `bart` to the `maggie` group, then anyone who is in the group `maggie`, like you and `bart` will be able to access those files.  There is a setuid concept for directories, but it is not implemented.  The alternative is posix ACLs, which has pros and cons, but for what you need, setgid directories might work.

Comment: Setuid on directories is a great way to get around disk quotas. You would also have to work around `cp --preserve=mode` when the owner changes but the executable is suid.